# How to check user like a post in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I wanna know a user who like post or not by post id

facebook graph api i only found a post details (/{post_id})
and take its liker array, but it cost too many request and time

does any api function could directly check a post liked or not?

thanks for your reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this directly with Graph API.

You have 2 options to find this :

**Option #1** :
Requesting the api to find every people who likes a specific post, with this kind of request :
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150217223114971%2Flikes%3Ffields%3Did
Caution : This method will ony return you the last 5k likers ID

**Option #2** :
Use FQL and requesting "like" table : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/